# When deploying a database project with vsdbcmd I get the error "Vardecimal support is enabled for the database but disabled for the project"

Tags: database-project, datadude, vsdbcmd

I get: `SQL01265 Vardecimal support is enabled for the database but disabled for the project`

I've tried changing the .sqlsettings files to have: `"<VardecimalStorageFormatOn>True</VardecimalStorageFormatOn>"` and the .sqldeployment file to have: `"<DeployDatabaseProperties>True</DeployDatabaseProperties>"` But i'm still getting the error.

It's VS2010 DB Project with the project set to 2005, the database being upgraded is 2008.

We've got another 2005 DB project which will update a 2008 db fine, even with VardecimalStorageFormatOn set to false in the .sqlsettings file and not deploying db properties.

Any idea why one would work and the other wouldn't?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem until I changed this line in the "Properties\Database.sqlcmdvars" file...

```
<SqlCommandVariables xmlns="urn:Microsoft.VisualStudio.Data.Schema.Package.SqlCmdVars">
```

to

```
<SqlCommandVariables xmlns="urn:Microsoft.VisualStudio.Data.Schema.Package.SqlCmdVars" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
```

Funny thing is that if you change it back, it still works.  It may be an XML schema caching thing.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. We tried this but it didn't make any difference. Oddly enough it worked fine when restoring the database a second time and trying it again, which is odd as the database restore seemed fine & could query it ok etc

Answer (score 0):

Had same problem, until I changed the compatability level in the GDR project down to SQL 2000 (by mistake) then back up to 2005 again. After a rebuild, the project deployed ok (to the 2008 server).

Go figure...

Answer (score 0):

Another place to check is in the database project file.

For VS2012, for me, Visual Studio was overriding the VardecimalStorageFormatOn in the sqlsettings file with the same setting in the sqlproj file and copying the project setting to the Model.xml deployment setting file. This then caused the error message and prevented the deploy, even when I was deploying to SQL Server 2008 with compatibility level 100.